# Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS update does not work - no release file / GPG errors

Tags: apt, package-management

[image: The Terminal Update(Screenshot)]

When I try to update my laptop running Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS I use the commands `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt-get update` and every time I get this message:

```
E: The repository 'cdrom://Ubuntu 18.04 LTS _Bionic Beaver_ - Release amd64 (20180426) bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: https://dl.bintray.com/resin-io/debian stable Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 379CE192D401AB61
E: The repository 'https://dl.bintray.com/resin-io/debian stable Release' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Has the OS updated? What should I do so that it updates?

Comment: Don't provide information as image which can be text.

Answer (score 6):

Just remove your repository above from sources.list,

```
The repository 'cdrom://Ubuntu 18.04 LTS _Bionic Beaver_ - Release amd64
```

and try update and upgrade again your system.

Hope this helps.

Comment: How to remove this Repository ?? Is there a command for it??

Comment: just edit your sources.list at `/etc/apt/sources.list` find your `'cdrom://Ubuntu 18.04 LTS _Bionic Beaver_` and add `#` .

Comment: may also need to remove files from /etc/apt/sources.list.d

Comment: @vpathak when the error still appears, i think the sources list daemon should be empty. to solve the OP questio just do two steps. remove 'cd-rom' repository and make a gpg key for Resin-IO :)

Answer (score 2):

With CDROM in the /etc/apt/sources.list you will not likely to find updates there. The RESIN repository will only find etcher, you can add the gpg key if you want to get rid of the error message.

To add an internet mirror, you can run this command to add an apt repository

`apt-add-repository http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu`

You can find official mirrors closer to you here:
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors